# Parsing file with multiple JSON entries in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I have a **JSON** file that I am trying to parse using Scala. I have figured out how to use Scala **JSON** parsing library to parse 1 entry in this format:

```
{"name":"John","number":"005","fav_colour":"blue"}
```

this is the code that works:

```
val result = JSON.parseFull("""{"name":"John","number":"005","fav_colour":"blue"}""")
result match {
  case Some(e) => println(e) 
  case None => println("Failed.")
}
```

This prints `Map(name -> John, number -> 005, fav_colour -> blue)`

The code is based of of this: https://gist.github.com/takezoe/1540223

However, I am working with a file like this:

> """ {"name":"John","number":"005","fav_colour":"blue"}
>   {"name":"Mary","number":"010","fav_colour":"yellow"}
>   {"name":"Anna","number":"007","fav_colour":"pink"}
>   {"name":"Dave","number":"003","fav_colour":"purple"}
>
> """

Note, I also tried separating with commas and still it did not work.

I am just wondering if I have to write a function to separate each {bracketed entry} or if there is some functionality of the **JSON** library that I am missing. So far, when I pass in my file it returns None instead of Some(valid information).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't qualify as a JSON file.

Comment: I know, I realized my file is a bunch of JSON files, a different one on each line. This is my first time working with them.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a valid Json file. This would be valid:

```
[
   {"name":"John","number":"005","fav_colour":"blue"},   
   {"name":"Mary","number":"010","fav_colour":"yellow"},
   {"name":"Anna","number":"007","fav_colour":"pink"}, 
   {"name":"Dave","number":"003","fav_colour":"purple"}
]
```

Result:
`Some(List(Map(name -> John, number -> 005, fav_colour -> blue), Map(name -> Mary, number -> 010, fav_colour -> yellow), Map(name -> Anna, number -> 007, fav_colour -> pink), Map(name -> Dave, number -> 003, fav_colour -> purple)))`

http://www.scalakata.com/522bdbfeebb25c7f5d823c7d

Comment: I am unable to change what I have

Answer (score 1):

The format you use is convenient for gathering information over time, e.g. keeping logs.

You can parse it by reusing the parser combinators!
For example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
val parseResult = JSON.rep1(JSON.root)(new JSON.lexical.Scanner("{\"a\": 1} {\"b\": 2}"))
parseResult match {case JSON.Success (result, _) => result; case _ => Nil}
```

returns

```
List({"a" : 1.0}, {"b" : 2.0})
```